# Create categories in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, categories

I've created a Vocabulary (Taxonomy) named Categories, with list terms: Category1, Category2, Subcategory1 etc.

Now if I want to create an article here doesn't appear any field where I can select the Category of article...

So, I've tried to add a "list text" field in Content Types at articles but I haven't any option to have a dropdown list f categories that I make.

I'm a Drupal begginer, and I like it so much because is very flexible.
If tis is not the best location to ask this, you can tell me, and I will delete this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to admin/structure/types and select "Manage fields" for the article content type.

Add a new field of type "Term reference" press save and you will be redirected to a page where you can select the Taxonomy that you created.

Your Taxonamy will now appear in the add content articles page node/add/article .

Answer (score 1):

Create a field called 'Term reference' in your article content type.  This will allow you to add taxonomy terms to your article content type.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 6 or 7, You can visit [here](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/drupal-7-taxonomy/) too